# How to declare group of strings as a type?

Tags: typescript

I would like to enforce a group of strings as a strict type. Users should be only be able to pass in anything that matches a string in the group. How would I go about implementing this?

This is what I have so far:

```
const types: Array<string> = [ 'text', 'password' ];

interface IAbstractFormElement {

  value: string;
  type: Array<types>;
  required?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;

}
```

Current error: `Cannot find name 'types'` which almost seems like a scope issue to me.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying here. Are you trying to make it that `type` can only be one of two values, and this is enforced by the compiler?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Exactly!

Comment: It's yet not clear what you want. Will it always be `"text"` or `"password"` or can change?

Comment: @NitzanTomer If will always _have_ to be one of the strings in the array. Only one.

Comment: You cannot have a type which is the values of an array. The only way you can do anything like so will require you to know what are the possible values in this array in advance.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I _do_ know what will be the possible values in the array in advance, all inputs that accept in input `type` attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know in advance what are the possible values are for the `type` property then you can use [string literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types):

```
type types = "text" | "password";

const types: types[] = ["text", "password"];

interface IAbstractFormElement {
    value: string;
    type: types;
    required?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20memoize%3CR%2C%20T%20extends%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20R%3E(f%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20memory%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20R%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20g%20%3D%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!memory.get(args.join()))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20memory.set(args.join()%2C%20f(...args))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20memory.get(args.join())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20g%20as%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20exp%20%3D%20memoize((text%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20RegExp(text.replace(%2F%5B%5Ea-zA-Z0-9%5Cs%5D%2Fg%2C%20%22.%22).replace(%2F%5Cs%2B%2Fg%2C%20%22%5C%5Cs%2B%22)%2C%20%22ig%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B#src=type%20types%20%3D%20%22text%22%20%7C%20%22password%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20types%3A%20types%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%22text%22%2C%20%22password%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IAbstractFormElement%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20types%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20required%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20disabled%3F%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D))

Comment: Thanks! this put me on the right track. Didn't need line two.

Comment: Yeah, that was my guess as well, but just to be sure I included it (also it shows that you can use the same name `type` for both the type and the variable)

Comment: I updated the title and description to better reflect what I was trying to do. Thanks again.

Comment: What's wrong with `type types = "text" | "password";`?

Comment: @NitzenTomer Not sure if someone deleted their comment, but your solution was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `types` isn't a type, it's a const value. You will have to take a different approach.

---

One approach is to use an enumeration:

```
enum InputType {
    Text = 1,
    Password  = 2
}

let t: InputType = InputType.Text;
```

But enumerations are really just a named number. There isn't any safety enforced by the compiler.

For example, the typescript compiler would compile, without error, nonsense like this:

```
let t:InputType = InputType.Text;
t = InputType.Password;
t = 72;
t = Math.PI;
```

---

To strictly enforce a limited number of values, you can create a dedicated class:

```
class InputType {
    private static Instances = {
        Text: new InputType("text"),
        Password: new InputType("password")
    };

    private constructor(private _name:string) {
    }

    get Name() : string {
        return this._name;
    }

    static get Password() : InputType{
        return InputType.Instances.Password;
    }

    static get Text(): InputType{
        return InputType.Instances.Text;
    }
}
```

Because the constructor is private, the rest of your code cannot create one of these. It will have to access a predefined value via a static getter method.

Using this in the interface you defined:

```
interface IAbstractFormElement {
  value: string;
  type: InputType;
  required?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

var nameControl = <IAbstractFormElement>{
     value: 'Harold',
     type: InputType.Text
};
var passwordControl = <IAbstractFormElement>{
     value: 'P@ssw0rd',
     type: InputType.Password
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the Custom type as a user defined type as below

```
interface IAbstractFormElement {

  value: string;
  type: Array<Types>;
  required?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;

}

export interface Types{
     text:string;
     password:string;
}
```

More than custom array type, I would prefer Enums in this case

```
enum Types {
    text
    password
}


interface IAbstractFormElement {

      value: string;
      type: Types;
      required?: boolean;
      disabled?: boolean;

    }
```